# Javascript html call external object from external file

Tags: javascript, html, scope

This works ...

html file ...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/myJS.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="myJS();">
</body>
</html>
```

Contents of external javascript file (called myJS.js for convenience) ...

```
myJS = function ()
{
    document.write("Hello world");
};
```

But, this does not work ...

html file ...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/myJS.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="myJS.myFunction();">
</body>
</html>
```

external javascript file ...

```
myJS = function ()
{   
    myFunction = function()
    {
        document.write("Hello world");
    };  
};
```

Why not? Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A function declared inside another function does not become a property of that function.
If you want myJS to be an object with myFunction as a method you can do this

```
myJS = {    
    myFunction: function()
    {
        document.write("Hello world");
    }   
};
```

Comment: Would this be an example of closures?

Comment: @MartinJacobs No, just an object with a method.

Answer (score 0):

your script creates two global functions...

so the `myJS` creates another function called `myFunction` either of which can be called independently.

looks like you want to make a JSON object like

```
myJS = {   
    myFunction: function() {
        document.write("Hello world");
    }
}
```